# Плагин WordPress Dynamic Text Extension для Contact Form 7 - не с первого раза подставляет значение, почему?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, contact-form7

Уже всю голову сломал, Dynamic Text Extension не с первого раза подставляет значение в поле формы.

Код в function.php:

```
function utm_term_cf7_func() {
$val = $_COOKIE['utm_term'];
return $val;
}
add_shortcode('utm_term', 'utm_term_cf7_func');
```

В Contact Form 7: `[dynamichidden utm_term "utm_term"]`

В итоге в форме value без значения, просто value даже без знака равно после него. Но если обновить страницу, то в value значение подставляется. Уже голову сломал, почему так происходит понять не могу.

```
<input type="hidden" name="utm_term" value size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7dtx-dynamictext wpcf7-dynamichidden" aria-invalid="false">
```

Сами кукисы сохранены, проверял, utm_term сохранен. Код сохранения: `if(isset($_GET["utm_term"])) setcookie("utm_term",$_GET["utm_term"],time()+3600*24*30,"/");`

Comment: Проблема, скорее всего в том, что кукисы ставятся поздно, после того, как начат любой вывод на страницу. Это ограничение протокола http.

Comment: @KAGG Design а что с этим можно сделать, как исправить?

Comment: Отправлять куки как можно раньше, наприсер, на событии init.

Comment: Куда только эту отправку куков не прикручивал, и в index.php и в конфиг файл ВордПресса и еще в другие файлы - всегда куки отправляются позже, чем получаются. В итоге в код формы, в скрытый инпут, попадает старая utm метка, либо если старой не было, то вообще ничего не попадает. В общем пришел к тому что проверяю $_GET и если в нем есть utm метки, значит пользователь по ссылке с метками пришел и не успел еще на другие страницы перейти, так что из этого массива надо их забирать. Если там они отсутствуют, то искать в  $_COOKIE.

Comment: То, что вы не справились с куки, это не показатель того, что они не работают. Почитайте, что такое минимальный, самодостаточный, воспроизводимый пример. Опубликуйте его в качестве нового вопроса и мы поможем.

Comment: На мой взгляд, дело не столько в куках, сколько в каком то из звеньев WordPress - Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension - PHP обработчик формы. Не уверен, что пример в этом случае возможно сделать минимальным. Для минимальности придется сперва самому понять, какое из звеньев мешает использовать cookie в обработчике. Но я уже решил проблему другим способом и не вижу теперь смысла разбираться.